# Glassfish: java.net.BindException: No free port within range

Tags: glassfish-3, eclipse-indigo

Good evening, i'm facing a weird problem in glassfish 3.1.2, whenever i run my application(it doesn't run) and i looked at eclipse console, i found these strange exception:

```
SEVERE: doSelect IOException java.net.BindException: No free port within range: 8181=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@188fcca7
at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.initSelector(TCPSelectorHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.preSelect(TCPSelectorHandler.java:378)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.doSelect(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:188)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.run(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: doSelect IOExceptionjava.net.BindException: No free port within range: 3700=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ServiceInitializerHandler@1b42f99d
at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.initSelector(TCPSelectorHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.preSelect(TCPSelectorHandler.java:378)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.doSelect(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:188)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.run(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

i changed some configuration in `domain.xml` inside `glassfish\domains\domain1\config` i increased the following 2 elements but nothing changed

```
 <jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvm-options>
 <jvm-options>-XX:PermSize=512m</jvm-options>
```

could anyone help me.

Note: i killed java.exe from process list as sehrope suggests and the exception resolved but the server redirects me to the `HTTP Status 404` page, the requested resource is not available(), for more clarity, here's my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Gambak</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the file `login.xhtml` is located under `WebContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an existing server running on that port. Check your process list ot see if anything is running in the background and listening on those ports.

```
$ sudo netstat -lpn | grep 8181
```

If there is something running the kill the process and try restarting your server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and in the `domain.xml` was a wrong IP configured as `address` attribute in the `<network-listener` tag...